# Changing URL of Wishlist without change to core code

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, wishlist, ce-1.9.2.2, router

I'm working on Magento CE 1.9.2.2 site and want to change the URL to the Wishlist that comes with Magento.

I tried to copy `app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/etc/config.xml` to `app/code/local/Mage/Wishlist/etc/config.xml` and change the following:

```
<routers>
    <wishlist>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
            <module>Mage_Wishlist</module>
            <frontName>moodboard</frontName>
        </args>
    </wishlist>
</routers>
```

The intention is to change the URL to **/moodboard** as opposed to **/wishlist**.

This doesn't work. However if I edit the core version of the file (in `app/code/core/`) it works.

I've disabled the cache, reindexed, etc etc and it doesn't work.

Obviously I don't want to edit core code so am trying to make my changes in `app/code/local`. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: This is a solution which worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047194/change-wishlist-url-in-magento

Answer (score 0):

I’ll give this a stab.

Copying files from core -> local will work for files that are autoloaded. The modules `config.xml` is not autoloaded it is instead defined the the `app/etc/modules/Whatever_Whatever.xml` file which specifies the code pool from which to load the module from.

If you simply want to overwrite the xml you could do the following steps

1. Create a new module called `Namespace_Wishlist`
2. Make that module depend on `Mage_Wishlist` in the `app/etc/modules/Namespace_Wishlist.xml` file. This is so that it is loaded after `Mage_Wishlist`.
3. Define the same xml that you have above in your new modules `app/code/local/Namespace/Wishlist/etc/config.xml`.

When magento merges the global config, your modules should overwrite the core values.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. Making a new module, just to change the URL used by another module, seems a little backward to me.

Comment: It is a little backwards but you have to leverage how XML is merged if you want to avoid touching core files.  Are you sure your custom module is installed correctly? Don't forget you will have to clear the config cache.

Comment: Sorry, to complicate matters further there was actually a third party wishlist extension installed and I believe this is configured to use the URL /wishlist. That possibly explains why my initial modification didn't work - as it wasn't using the standard Magento functionality. I'm not sure if I set things up correctly according to your instructions, but I managed to override the URL in app/etc/local.xml (see Answer as a comment on my question). Thanks for your advice though.

Comment: Cool. Yeah that answer does a similar thing under the hood. I just try to keep my `local.xml` clean and only to define how the site is connecting to databases and where to store sessions etc. I usually try and store changes like this in the app/code structure so that it can easily be shared and discovered by developers.